# Spring batch 2.2 JavaConfig

Tags: java, spring, annotations, spring-batch

I'm trying to get Spring Batch 2.2 working with JavaConfig.

Nowadays they have a `@EnableBatchProcessing` annotation that sets up a lot of things.
Default that annotation uses a datasource for its job data, but we don't want to save this data and don't want to create the table for it. The documentation says something about customizing but I have not been able to get it working:

- The user has to provide a `DataSource` as a bean in the context, or else implement `BatchConfigurer` in the configuration class itself, e.g.:

`public class AppConfig extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {`

In our older version we've been able to use `MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean` class so it keeps all its data in memory. Is there anyway to use the full JavaConfig way and not define a `DataSource`? I've not been able to get it working.

Even if I define two data sources (one HSQL in-memory that never gets used) and our real Oracle datasource it does not work because it finds two data sources instead of one.

Anyone have an idea how to get this working? Or is the only solution going back to configuring this in the XML way?

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that no other artifacts require a DataSource, you can use java config to create a context without a DataSource.  To do that, your configuration will need to extend DefaultBatchConfigurer as you point out.  In there, you'll override two methods, createJobRepository() and setDataSource().  Below is an example context (it doesn't define a job or steps, but it bootstraps all the related beans correctly).

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public static class BatchConfiguration extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {

    @Override
    protected JobRepository createJobRepository() throws Exception {
        MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = 
            new MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean();
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return  (JobRepository) factory.getObject();
    }

    @Override
    @Autowired
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        if(dataSource != null) {
            super.setDataSource(dataSource);
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I do think that simplifying this would be a useful feature and have added it to Jira.  You can track it's progress here: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/BATCH-2048

Comment: In our case the problem is that we do need another datasource for our business logic. As mentioned in the question, if you do that an exception will be thrown because there are two datasources found..

Comment: Just to confirm...you're looking for javaconfig with two datasources and using the map job repository, correct?

Comment: What we were trying to do is use our datasource for business logic and use an embedded repository for spring batch itself. It was too much of a hassle so we went with the XML way for the job config itself. Thanks for your response though!

Comment: You can create a data source for the job using MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean and AppConfig extending DefaultBatchConfigurer & have a secondary data source for business logic. However the database type is determined implicitly using metadata of the secondary data source. It works fine for Oracle, however a provider like Sybase IQ, it fails. You may need to use a JobRepositoryFactoryBean and set the database type manually to Sybase in that case.

Comment: @MichaelMinella, you pointed to Jira issue that is fixed now. But I can't find in docs what is new Java config usage in version 3.0.0.

Comment: See here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/EnableBatchProcessing.html

Answer (score -1):

Just define a dataSource() method in your BatchConfig Class
Here is how

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
    dataSource.setUrl(driverUrl);
    dataSource.setUsername(driverUsername);
    dataSource.setPassword(driverPassword);
    return dataSource;
}
```

This will automatically be invoked while setting up the TransactionManager