# How can I configure Spring Batch StepScope using java-based configuration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I'm setting up a job server using Spring Batch.   My JdbcCursorItemReader needs to be configured with sql that changes on a per-job run basis.  Because the sql changes, I want the reader to have @StepScope so I don't need to worry about sql statefulness.

So I've setup a class like this:

```
public class ParameterSettingJdbcCursorItemReader extends JdbcCursorItemReader implements StepExecutionListener {

    @Override
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {

        JobParameters jobParameters = stepExecution.getJobParameters();

        if (jobParameters != null) {
            List<Object> args = new ArrayList<Object>();
            for (JobParameter jobParameter : jobParameters.getParameters().values()) {
                args.add(jobParameter.getValue());
            }

            Object[] arrayArgs = args.toArray(new Object[args.size()]);
            String sql = String.format(getSql(), arrayArgs);
            setSql(sql);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The idea is that I pass sql parameters to the object via JobParameters and use String.format to fill in the dynamically-changing sql.

I am using Java-based configuration throughout my server.  My bean for one instance of my ItemReader looks like:

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public ItemReader<MyInputObject> myInputObjectItemReader() {
    ParameterSettingJdbcCursorItemReader itemReader = new ParameterSettingJdbcCursorItemReader();
    itemReader.setDataSource(myDataSource());
    itemReader.setSql("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE date = '%1$s'");
    itemReader.setRowMapper(myInputObjectMapper);
    return itemReader;
}
```

When I start up my server and run the Spring Batch job, I get this error: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Scope registered for scope 'step'`

I've read elsewhere that in order to be able to use StepScope, one needs to first add it to the xml app configuration like this : 
`<bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope" />`

But since I'm using Java-based configuration, that's not an option.

So how do I register the StepScope via a Java-based config?   I've tried this:

```
@Bean
public org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope stepScope() {
    return new org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope();
}
```

... but when I do I get all sorts of NPEs during app startup on beans that have no relation to StepScope.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/codecentric/spring-batch-javaconfig/blob/master/src/test/java/de/codecentric/batch/FlatfileToDbWithParametersAutowiringJobTests.java) seems to be similar to what you're trying to do. The author wrote a [blog](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2013/06/spring-batch-2-2-javaconfig-part-2-jobparameters-executioncontext-and-stepscope/) to explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to register the scope with the `ApplicationContext`. Normally that would be done for you when you use `@EnableBatchProcessing`. Did you do that (add that annotation to one of your `@Configurations`)?

Comment: I'm not using the `@EnableBatchProcessing` annotation. I tried it initially, but ran into issues, because I have 4 data sources in the app.  I tried creating a unique BatchConfigurer for each data source - with `@EBP` on each - but I still get the same error about multiple data sources.   So I guess what I'm looking for is to see how StepScope is enabled underneath the covers when `@EBP` is set and then just add that to my config instead of `@EBP`.  Alternatively, if you know how I can get around the multiple data sources issue created by `@EBP`, that'd be fine too.

Comment: Why would you need 4 `BatchConfigurers`? One of the `DataSources` has to be for the Batch repository. If you can identify it somehow (e.g. call that "dataSource" or mark it `@Primary`) you can write one `BatchConfigurer` that creates a `JobRepository` from it.

Comment: A little investigation into DefaultBatchConfigurer revealed that it needs the data source to store the job repo.  So I used an answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17090739/spring-batch-2-2-javaconfig) - though using a `@Resource(name="myDataSource")` annotation instead of `@Autowired` - to help set that up.  That gave me use of the `@StepScope` on my ItemReader beans.  I still had to provide a proxyMode of TARGET_CLASS on the scope annotation, else Tomcat wouldn't start.

Comment: yeah, I discovered the same once I realized why it needed the data source.  I should have dug into the DefaultBatchConfigurer source earlier on.

Answer (score 1):

+1 to Dave's point about using @EanbleBatchProcesssing.  That will add a `StepScope` to your context.  However, your code still won't work once you've done that because you're returning an ItemReader for "myInputObjectItemReader" instead of `ParameterSettingJdbcCursorItemReader`.  See the issue here for details on why that matters: [Spring-batch @BeforeStep does not work with @StepScope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21241683/spring-batch-beforestep-does-not-work-with-stepscope/21941127#21941127)

Comment: Appreciate the heads up.  Return type has been modified and works well.